# Creating a TSQL Shortcut for Converting to String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'd like to write a user-defined function on SQL Server 2012 that converts any value to String/Text.

When i inspect SQL Server, the type of Convert function parameter is "expression", but I don't seem to be able to use this type for my own user-defined function. Is there any other alternative?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Text]
(
    @value expression
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN Convert(nvarchar(max), @value);
END
```

I receive the following error message:

**Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type expression.**

Comment: Why are you doing this?  You are just wrapping the existing Convert function into another function.

Comment: It might appear as crazy idea, but it helps with abstracting the coding effort and handling nulls in formula expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to with the built in function, I don't know. However, the data type you want is sql_variant

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Text]
(
    @value sql_variant
)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in case anyone is interested:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Text]
(
    @value SQL_VARIANT
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN Convert(nvarchar(max), ISNULL(@value,''));
END
```

Seems to do what I need it to.

Comment: I just found it too, you beat me to it :) Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx